# Return each expression=value pair for given string

Tags: regex

I'm facing a regexp issue which has been causing me headaches for hours now. I'm trying to create a regexp which will return each expression=value pair in a given SQL query. For example:

- given `(YEAR(created) = ? OR YEAR(created) = ?)` I want two groups, `YEAR(created) = ?` and `YEAR(created) = ?`.
- given `DATE_FORMAT(col, "%d-%m") = ?` I want one group, `DATE_FORMAT(col, "%d-%m") = ?`
- etc.

I think I'm very close: https://regex101.com/r/mX7sO8/1 . All examples are looking good to me, except for the fact that I cannot get example one to work correctly (I want two groups, not one).

Can someone point me in the right direction here?

Comment: What's your rule for matching groups ?

Comment: Could you tell us **why** you need to do this (so we understand better **what** you're trying to do)?

Comment: Your expression starts with `(?:(?:<stuff>))`. Surely you don't need to nest those non-capturing groups? It adds confusion.

Comment: I cleaned up your RegEx, check out the [new demo](https://regex101.com/r/mX7sO8/2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First inspect for alphabets followed by optional parenthesis containing any characters then followed by `=` and `?`

Try below regex

```
[`\w]+(?:\([^\(]+\))?\s*=\s*\?
```

Regex explanation:

```
  [`\w]+         any character of: '`', word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or more times)
  (?:            group, but do not capture (optional):
    \(              '('
    [^\(]+              any character except: '\(' (1 or more times)
    \)               ')'
  )?             end of grouping
  \s*            whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or more times)
  =              '='
  \s*            whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or more times)
  \?             '?'
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/nN8hM1/6)

Comment: Please let me know if any test cases are failed so that we can modify it.

Comment: This seems to be matching lots of extraneous characters because you didn't specify a closing `\)` in your non-capturing group.

Comment: Updated the regex a little: `(?:\w+|\`\w+\`)(?:\([^\(]+)?\s*=\s*\?`. Now it also matches `\`foo\`=?` queries. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm. Still seems to have an issue with grouping multiple lines. Can you have a look at this updated example? https://regex101.com/r/nN8hM1/4

Comment: @glcheetham thanks for the correction. updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

I've written this that seems to match your test cases (And I've tried to make it match valid SQL that isn't in your test cases too)

```
[`\w"]+(\([\w\s,"%-]+\))?\s?=\s?\?
```

https://regex101.com/r/lF9hZ4/1

Let's break it down really quick

```
[`\w"]+
```

One or more of any letter, backtick (`) or quotation mark (")

```
(\([\w\s,"%-]+\))?
```

Followed by an optional group of: optional parenthesis `\(`, followed by one or more of any letter, whitespace character, comma (,), percent sign (%), or hypen(-) `[\w\s,"%-]+`, followed by another optional parenthesis `\)`.

```
\s?=\s?
```

Followed by an equals (=) sign optionally surrounded by whitespace

```
\?
```

Followed by a question mark

Comment: I would like to maximise reuseability. That's why I choose to do a `.+` instead of `[\w\s,"%-]+` between the parenthesis. Any thoughts?

Comment: If you do the `.+` then you match *anything*, even invalid characters for SQL query. I decided to specify the character set explicitly to limit what will be matched, but IHMO it's not that much of a difference if you're writing sane SQL anyway

Answer (score 0):

The problem you were having was that the `.+` in `\w+\(.+\)` was matching too much. The trick to seeing this is to remove the `?:` to capture the first group so that regex101 can show you that it captured `YEAR(created) = ? OR YEAR(created)` (the `.+` corresponds to `created) = ? OR YEAR(created`). The solution is simply to add a `?` after `.+` sot that it becomes lazy instead of greedy.

Your solution is quite complicated and deals with too many special cases, especially at the beginning. Perhaps you would be better off splitting at operators such as `OR`?